# Self Signed Certificated generated from IIS Manager giving error?

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, iis

I am hosting an ASP.NET Core app with Self Signed Certificated generated from IIS Manager. But it is giving errors and chrome browser is not allowing website to open.

I am generating Self Signed Certificate as given on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis).

In the first Image see I have generated it.
[image]

Next I am binding it to 443 port of my website.
[image]

Now when I open the website I get error - **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** as shown below:

[image]

I click on **Proceed to myiisapp.com (unsafe)** and this time I get error **ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE** and chrome is not opening the website.

[image]

I would expect the website to open on the browser with a warning for self-signed certificate.

If I generate the Self-signed certificate from powershell as given on:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-pfxcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Then chrome is opening the website with a warning.

My question is that is IIS Manager certificate generation method broken or I am missing something??

**Update - More information**

The error screenshot from Edge browser is:

[image]

The PEM of the certificate is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I think the problem is that, by enabling SNI, the TLS handshake is trying to reach myiisapp.com but the certificate was generated with the PCs hostname. Try generating a new certificate without SNI and see if that works

Comment: I am generating the certificate as given on the docs. They have not given anything about SNI etc.

Comment: The docs you linked don't check "Require Server Name Indication"

Comment: Yes I have checked without Require Server Name Indication also but the problem persists.

Comment: @yogihosting: Different browsers behave differently in such cases. Try to open using MS Edge: in this case more information can be obtained by using software of the same manufacturer on both sides.

Comment: @MateusZampol: It has nothing to do with SNI.

Comment: The IIS wizard is too weak in features for modern browsers. You might check out the one from Jexus Manager https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html

Comment: @Jackdaw i have added more information to question regarding edge browser error.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk added certificate code to question now.

Comment: @LexLi i also thing this wizard is not working anymore. Since Powershell certificate generation works properly.

Comment: I looked at the certificate, and basically the error messages are accurate. There *is* a host name in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extension, but it's `DESKTOP-QR5LPHK` which is evidently not what you want to use in your URL to connect. Secondly, the Key Usage extension is not valid. Conclusion: Don't use IIS to generate certificates.

Comment: Once you have a new server certificate generated and associated with the site binding, run a report to learn if any common issues remain, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html BTW, if you use the wrong URL (not matching the CN/SAN of the server certificate), then the browser warning is expected. They must match for modern browsers to trust the connection is secure.

Comment: This thread is similar to your question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1517411/how-to-fix-the-err-ssl-key-usage-incompatible-micr

Answer (score 0):

I've just delete all SSL self signed certificates, then I've tried Jexus Manager as @Lex-li recommendation and created a new self signed ssl. The browser changed the error from ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE to "This site is not secure", I bypassed the error typing thisisunsafe on an empty area of Edge browser and works well for test my application.